# I start blender from the command line with the -d option but didn't see any command output

Tags: navigation

I want to navigate the code, so I start blender from the command line with the -d option but didn't see any command output on console, how can I print command to console

I only got these output, and it didn't have new message after I add a cube
[image]

Comment: are u looking in blender console? if yes, just look at the window from which you started blender (where you typed in your command line)

Comment: there is no command output after operations